# ActionScript Managing Camera on Air Application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Does anyone know the name of the event that is dispatch by the attachCamera(), i would like to   take a picture ones the camera is loaded, i try to execute my code after call attachCamera but it takes the VideoDisplay empty, that's why i would like to know if there is an event triggered after the attachcamera() is complete loeaded.

Comment: umm.. i did not found any resource about event triggeret, i solve it using a timer.

Answer (score 1):

To "take" a picture, you'll need to draw a bitmap, which uses the camera input as it's source. You must define the x/y of the bitmap container and place it inside...

There are a number of things you can do with the bitmap once it's drawn...Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how the camera activity might work by looking at this [example in the Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera%28%29) on the Camera class.  Also, researching [how to use Video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d50.html) is useful in understanding how Air might use the camera feed (this relies on using the [Video class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html), of course).

Comment: i'm sorry man, i've just seen your comment, by the way've you ever try to manage the maximum quality of specific webcam?

Comment: I think that is better asked in another question (so that others can find the answers as well).

Answer (score 0):

A timer will work, but a more direct solution is to handle the first ActivityEvent dispatched by the Camera instance after Video.attachCamera() is called.  Like so:

```
var video:Video = new Video();
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, onCameraActivity);

private function onCameraActivity (evt:ActivityEvent) :void {
    camera.removeEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, onCameraActivity);

    // wait a bit to ensure the camera frame is not empty    
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(50, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,
        function (evt:TimerEvent) :void {
            timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, arguments.callee);

            // take snapshot here
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height);
            bitmapData.draw(video);
        }
    );
    timer.start();
}
```

EDIT: Some cameras take a bit of time to initialize, so capturing the first frame after ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY results in a blank frame. Added a brief timeout to address this.